# Google Assistant search in media app does not work

Tags: android, actions-on-google, exoplayer, google-assistant

i followed this guide [The Google Assistant and media apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant) but the
`onPrepareFromSearch() or onPlayFromSearch()` seems to be never called.

Using the Assistant in [DHU](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu)
i see the following logs.

> Unable to perform playFromMedia because the mediaId is missing from the MediaItem.
> Could not execute playFromUri, playFromMediaId or playFromSearch

My implementation is very close to the [UMP](https://github.com/android/uamp/) and i also checked
[VLC](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android) they both work. I use `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.mediasession.MediaSessionConnector`

The strangest things is, that i can successfully test every capability using [media controller test app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/media-controller-test)
(Playing by search, play by media id, play by uri, search and play, browse and play)

Using the [media controller test app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/media-controller-test) i can also verify that my media is active during voice command.
What is also very irritating that pause, play, next and previous works. So the media session is found. Session needs to be set to active.

Any hint would be welcome. Do i need some special registration? There is no default player set in the assistant settings.

This is my onGetRoot. There is no permission check.

```
override fun onGetRoot(
    clientPackageName: String,
    clientUid: Int,
    rootHints: Bundle?
): BrowserRoot {
    val maximumRootChildLimit = rootHints?.getInt(
        MediaConstants.BROWSER_ROOT_HINTS_KEY_ROOT_CHILDREN_LIMIT,
        /* defaultValue= */ 4)
    val supportedRootChildFlags = rootHints?.getInt(
        MediaConstants.BROWSER_ROOT_HINTS_KEY_ROOT_CHILDREN_SUPPORTED_FLAGS,
        /* defaultValue= */ MediaBrowser.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE)

    val rootExtras = Bundle().apply {
        putBoolean(
            "android.media.browse.SEARCH_SUPPORTED",
            true
        )
    }

    return BrowserRoot(ALBUMS_ROOT, rootExtras)
}
```

And here is the service in the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".service.MediaPlaybackService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    tools:ignore="ExportedService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976075/18286294)

```html
  <!-- for media search (Play X in Y) -->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

I was missing the

> category